# Visual Studio 2015: Getting "non standard syntax, use '&' to create a pointer to member" error

Tags: c++, compilation

Super confused as to what is throwing the error when I try to compile my code. I'm currently trying to test a function I wrote by printing out the values it should extract from a file.

gameboard.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream> 
#include "error.h"

using namespace std;

int boardDim(ifstream & inputFile, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    inputFile.open; //error is thrown here
    if (!(inputFile.is_open())) {
        throw fileNotOpen;
    }
    else {
        stringstream output(inputFile.getline); //error is also thrown here
        if (output >> x) {
            if (output >> y) {
                return success;
            }
            return secBoardVarErr;
        }
        return firstBoardVarErr;
    }
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

gameboard.h

```
#ifndef GAMEBOARD_H
#define GAMEBOARD_H

#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

//takes in dimensions of board from file
int boardDim(ifstream &, unsigned int, unsigned int);

#endif !GAMEBOARD_H
```

main function

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "gamepieces.h"
#include "gameboard.h"
#include "error.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ifstream x("test.txt");
    int test = 0;
    cout << boardDim(x, 0, 0) << endl;  
    return success;
}
```

I'm only testing the function I declared and defined in the gameboard header and source files, so the other included files will be used in the future but have already been tested and are not throwing errors when I compile and run it.

Thank you!

Comment: `inputFile.open; //error is thrown here` -- That is not the way you call a function in `C++`.  Where are the parentheses?  Strange that you left out the parentheses here, but didn't leave it out right after that for the `is_open()` function.

Comment: @paulMcKenzie, thank you! I'm still learning the language!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputFile.open` is a function, same with `inputFile.getline`, so what you have here is a syntactic error. The correct syntax is:

```
inputFile.open()
```

and

```
inputFile.getline()
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. i can't believe this was this mistake I was looking for, for about an hour.

Comment: @Harrison If this post has answered your question, please mark it so.

Comment: Not a problem. Be sure to upvote answers you find helpful. ;) Good luck in your C++ adventures; the compiler errors are often cryptic and misleading, so be on the lookout for things like that.

Comment: @arrowd, I was going to, but it stated I had to wait a certain amount of time before marking it answered.